# Best way to grant access to users after they purchase something

Tags: python, django

I am building an e-learning platform using Django and as part of the platform one can buy online courses.

For each course I have a manytomany field of users and every time a user purchases a course I add them to the field.

Is this a good approach to give users access to the course? What would your approach be in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the way I would go for it.

With such solution you can extend your manytomany table with fields like expiration date (so the users buy temporary access to the course), something like scope (so limit the user to just a part of a course) and you can e.g. group courses into packets and allow users to buy all of them.